# MSAccess: Change in subform recordsource causes loss of LinkChildFields binding

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a problem that Im completely stumped by.  Or rather, I have a work-around that is messy and I don't understand why what I want to do doesn't work:

I have a mainform / subform nest.  The subform is linked by master/child fields (neither form is editable- so Im using the recordsource field directly rather than a separate control).  The subform is a continuous form; so the subform displays the records related to the master in the mainform when the current record changes.  The subform is based on a query- there are no parameters or filters being applied- the query presents the recordset exactly as needed.  This all works perfectly (in that when the record of the mainform changes, so to do the related subform records).

Problem arises when I want the subform to be based on a different a different query (ie based on different tables)- but with the same unique-key (the 'ID') and fields as the original query.  The queries all work fine, and displaying them in the form works fine.

The issue arises when I change the recordsource of the subform (so from QueryA to QueryB).  The records the subform are correct (ie the query results are displayed as expected)- but the LinkChildFields is no longer functioning: the subform no longer shows the related records from the query- it displays them all.  In other words, the form displays the entire recordset as if I had no LinkChild / LinkMaster set.

So, the code in the AfterUpdate event of the toggle control in the MainForm is ;

```
Private Sub optActRep_AfterUpdate()

Select Case Me.optActRep
    Case 1
        MainFormSubFormControl.Form.RecordSource = "QueryA"
    Case 2
        MainFormSubFormControl.Form.RecordSource = "QueryB"
End Select
```

Ive debugged and the property 'linkchldfields' is still set correctly ('ID').  Ive tried setting these to vbNullString before the recordsource update and resetting after the recordsource update (same issue).  The odd thing is if I update the linkchildfield property in the mainform (in the Current Event)- then it works and seems to fire.  So,

```
Debug.print Me!Subform.LinkChildFields
```

correctly returns 'ID'.  The only way I can make it fire is by coding;

```
Me!Subform.LinkChildFields = "ID"
```

into the Current event of the Mainform (ie so that every time the MainForm record changes, the correct QueryB record is displayed)... even though Im only setting the property to what my debug is telling me it is already set to.  Its as if it no longer fires.

Very confused.

Comment: Have you tried just re-setting the value of `LinkChildFields` immediately after updating the `Form.RecordSource` in your VBA code?

Comment: Yes.  Ive even tried adding an additional different field to each query (say IDa and IDb) and using those as the Linked in part of the Case (to rule out it holding onto something from the original query).  It just stops firing.

Answer (score 2):

Access continues to do the daftest things.

Nothing to do with the form setup at all.  The underlying query (QueryB) was based on a Crosstab query.  Whilst the query worked fine independently of the form (including when directly using the query as the forms record source), it obviously didnt like using the product of one of the fields as the Unique key (even though it was the same format type and Grouped / Row rather than being a cross-tab field).

I changed the crosstab part of the query to a Grouped query (using IIF & Sum to manually create the Crosstab-equivalent field values) and the form now works fine.

My lesson learnt- don't use Crosstab queries!  Apologies for the red-herring.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. One issue that can arise with basic crosstab queries is that the column names *can* change based on the underlying data, so sometimes it is necessary to "hard code" the column headings in the `Column Headings` property of the query itself. Once that is done, other parts of Access will immediately "know" what the column names will be without actually running the query (which could take a long time for a large crosstab).

Comment: Many thanks.  I was actually using the crosstab out of sheer laziness on my part: the crosstab element I was after was count based on the result of only two conditions- so only took me about 2 minutes to rewrite the underlying query.  Compared with about a day working out that it was the query that was causing the error (rather than the crosstab)!  You live and learn...

Answer (score 0):

Surferosa
Apologies for the late reply, I only found this thread when I encountered problems similar to yours. I'm not sure the Crosstab query is the cause of your problem.
I can set LinkMasterFields to be either a column name or a control name.
I can only set LinkChildFields to be a column name, setting it to a control name does NOT work. Ouch.
You can change LinkChildFields in the sub-form control either in Design View or via VBA, but in many cases Access continues to use the previous value even though it displays the new value. This is true for sub-forms whose record source is either a table or a simple two table query. I do not have the time or the patience to characterise this problem any further. Sorry !
My solution is to set LinkChildFields in the sub-form control to a value e.g 'ID' and then create an alias with that name in each and every record source used by my different sub-forms. Then you only need to change the Source Object when you switch sub-forms.
Hope this helps !
HB